# BufferedWriter not creating and writing to file and no errors

Tags: java, file

I wanted to play around with arrays so I made this program. It's supposed to create 50 files with the *names of each state + random number + ".array"*

However, when I run this program, nothing is happening at all, no exceptions are being thrown.

```
package arraycraze;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayCraze {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random r = new Random();
        String[] names = {"Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"};
        for (int i = 0; i == names.length; i++) {
            File file = new File("C:/Users/" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "/AppData/Roaming/" + names[i] + +r.nextInt() + ".array");
            try {
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
                fw.write(names[i]);
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: downvoter explain your downvote

Comment: the error was pretty obvious and could have been easily found if it was reviewed! That's why the downvote!

Comment: @kiner_shah what if the OP is not even a teenager and is trash at Java? It might be easy for you to figure out problems, but not for me.

Comment: agreed with you but you should have an habit of reviewing your code. Even if you find some "suspect line" which you think may be causing the problem, you get close to isolating the problem. This problem was a bit too obvious, so I downvoted. No hard feelings mate! :-) For now, I am undoing my downvote!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
 for (int i = 0; i == names.length; i++) {
```

to

```
 for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
```

basically it never enters the loop as `i` is not equals to the length of `names.length`

Comment: It works now, thank you! This is the fastest response ever! I'll accept your answer when I can (12 minutes)